# Cannot display images in my JSX from my array.map in my react app even though .map loops though all index of array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, image, jsx

**The question**: why doesn't react display my image**s** in the JSX? How can I get it to display the image**s**?

**Edit:** the issue I suspect is not with the way I get the data but rather the way I try to display/render the image, which I have labeled under main issue below.

I have a functional component that has a useEffect to GET a JSON object from firebase.

```
useEffect(()=>{
        axios
        .get("http://localhost:9998/api/v1/fault/" + lastURLSegment)
        .then((response) => {
            setDisplay(response.data)
        })
    },[])
```

Then I extract the *imageURL* value and query firebase to return me a url viewable on the web
e.g [https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/${results.bucket}/o/${encodeURIComponent(item)}?alt=media](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/$%7Bresults.bucket%7D/o/$%7BencodeURIComponent(item)%7D?alt=media)

once I am able to get the URL for the image, I setState into an array called objUrl

edit: there is objOfUrl and objUrl, objOfUrl is a var [], objOfUrl is a state

```
useEffect(()=>{
        // displayspecificCases.imgURL = "fault/asd.jpg" 
        let foo = displayspecificCases.imageurl // "fault/asdfsdf.jpg,fault/1234.jpg..."
        if (foo !== undefined){
            console.log(foo) //console logs 2 images in string saperated by comma
            let bar = foo.split(','); // bar is now an array ['fault/asdfsdf.jpg','fault/1234.jpg']
            let i = 0;
            bar.map((item)=>{
                console.log(item)
                if(item !== ""){
                    firebase.storage().ref()
                    .child(item) 
                    .getMetadata()
                    .then((results) => {
                        objOfUrl[i] = `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/${results.bucket}/o/${encodeURIComponent(item)}?alt=media`
                        i++ // i ++ for objOfUrl
                        console.log("i is :" + i)
                        try{setObjUrl(objOfUrl)}catch(e){console.log("err is in view useEffect try catch e : " + e)}
                    })
                    .catch((err) => {
                    console.log(err);
                    });
                    console.log(objOfUrl); //console logs [0: "url.....", 1: "url....."]
                }
            })
        }

    },[displayspecificCases])
```

**Main issue is here!**
**So I want to display the images in JSX. So I setState the array into a state and tried to use .map to return each item in the array so I can use img tag to display them**

```
// inside the JSX
{objUrl.map((item, i) => { console.log(i); return <div class="column"> <img key={i} width="360px" height="270px" src={item} alt="no photo"/> </div>})}
```

But the problem right now is that only 1 image is displayed and not the whole array. Also whenever it renders, it seems to randomly display one of images inside the array. How do I display all images inside the array? many thanks!

sidenote: I know my code is messy, I'm still learning, please do give advice and tips on how to improve certain parts!

Comment: What is `objOfUrl`? Where is it declared/defined? My intuition says you are mutating your state object and not correctly updating state based upon the `objOfUrl[i] = '.......'` and `setObjUrl(objOfUrl)` lines.

Comment: Why not try Display.map instead of objUrl.map?
Isn't it where the images are located?

Comment: @DrewReese objOfUrl is an array var declared with the other constants. I will edit my question to include that. Regarding mutation of state object, when I do a console log it displayed both image URL, hope that clears things up. My issue right now is that the jsx is not rendering whatever is inside objUrl

Comment: Remember that on firebase storage you need to get a "downloadUrl" https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files so that you can display it

Comment: @CyrusZei i can display 1 picture but in the array there is 2 url, so supposedly its supposed to display 2 but theres only 1

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your code correctly it is doing:

1. Effect callback triggered by `displayspecificCases` updating
2. Split `displayspecificCases.imageurl` into array of urls
3. Call firebase backend for the bucket the image is in for the real image URL

## Issues

1. You are mutating your `objOfUrl` state object.

   ```
   objOfUrl[i] = `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/${results.bucket}/o/${encodeURIComponent(item)}?alt=media`
   ```
2. You enqueue standard state updates in a loop. This enqueues all state updates using the state value from the previous render cycle (remember state is `const`). This is also a problem since `objOfUrl` ***IS*** the state reference. It *should* be a new array reference.

   ```
   setObjUrl(objOfUrl)
   ```
3. I suppose this isn't a cause for your issue, but it is incorrect to use `array.prototype.map` to issue array side-effects.

## Solution

Use a functional state update to

1. Correctly enqueue state updates in a loop
2. Correctly return a new state array reference

Code

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (displayspecificCases.imageurl) {
    displayspecificCases.imageurl.split(",").forEach((item, i) => {
      console.log(item);
      if (item !== "") {
        firebase
          .storage()
          .ref()
          .child(item)
          .getMetadata()
          .then((results) => {
            // Construct complete image URL
            const url = `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/${
              results.bucket
            }/o/${encodeURIComponent(item)}?alt=media`;

            console.log("i is :" + i);
            try {
              // Update state array at index i
              setObjUrl((objOfUrl) =>
                objOfUrl.map((objUrl, index) => (index === i ? url : objUrl))
              );
            } catch (e) {
              console.log("err is in view useEffect try catch e : " + e);
            }
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
          });
      }
    });
  }
}, [displayspecificCases]);

// Log state when it updates
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(objOfUrl); //console logs [0: "url.....", 1: "url....."]
}, [objOfUrl]);
```

Comment: thanks for the solution, unfortunately, its either I messed up somewhere or the problems don't lie with the solution you have provided. After I implemented the code, I was still getting the same issue, which is the page only displaying 1 image. I have a strong suspicion the issue lies in the JSX and how I tried to render the image. But for the life of me, i just can't seem to find another way to render it.

Comment: Also, another question, under //Update state array at index i. I don't fully understand what the try-catch block is trying to achieve, in the anonymous function, the parameter objOfUrl is empty so how would the .map interact with that?

Comment: @daph99 Can you try creating a *running* codesandbox that reproduces the issue and link it in your question (and ping @ me here)? For the second question `objOfUrl` is an array, so as you are looping over the split image urls array you are building this state array up. The map is necessary since there is no guarantee of order when the firebase calls resolve, so you need the index to match the element by. I didn't really understand why there was a try/catch around a state update either, but your original snippet had it so I assumed it was there for a reason.

Comment: I think you were correct, but I was just too dumb to understand until i had someone to sit down and explain to me. Really appreciate your help though!

Answer (score 0):

### Solved


solution explained below

```
 useEffect(()=>{
        axios
        .get("http://localhost:9998/api/v1/fault/" + lastURLSegment)
        .then(async (response) => {
            setDisplay(response.data)
            const imagesToConstruct = await response.data.imageurl.slice(0,-1).split(",")
            // console.log(imagesToConstruct)
            imagesToConstruct.length > 0 && imagesToConstruct.forEach((item, i) => {
                if (item !== "") {
                firebase
                    .storage()
                    .ref()
                    .child(item)
                    .getMetadata()
                    .then((results) => { //main solution here
                        setImages((prevImages) => [...prevImages, `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/${results.bucket}/o/${encodeURIComponent(item)}?alt=media`])
                    }).catch((err) => {
                        console.log(err);
                    });
                }
            })            
        })
    }, [])
```

### The issue


Every time useEffect is called, the constructed url is parsed into a temp array **(objOfUrl)** which is setState into objUrl by using **setobjUrl(objOfUrl)** However, for some reason, i cannot figure out why it overwrites the state and the state only ends up with one constructed URL. So i had to consult someone to help with my code and this was the solution he provided.

**The solution explained**
Compressed the 2 useEffect into 1 and then set new state **(images)** using the spread operator.

Thank you to those who have attempted to help and replied to this post!